# How to split a file based on information within a column in linux

Tags: shell, text-processing, sed, awk

I would like to separate those rows where the value in second column is smaller than a specific value.

example input:

```
id1 19501112
id2 19831207
id3 20001212
id6 20000101
id10 20061213
id11 20081212
id12 20100109
id13 20101218
id14 20101212
id15 20111111
id16 20150919
id20 20141415
```

and I want to extract those rows whose second field's value is less than 20100101. So, my output would be:

```
id1 19501112
id2 19831207
id3 20001212
id6 20000101
id10 20061213
id11 20081212
```

any suggestion please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ awk '$2<20100101' file
id1 19501112
id2 19831207
1d3 20001212
id6 20000101
id10 20061213
id11 20081212
```

A typical awk program consists of commands that look like:

```
condition { action }
```

In our case, the *condition* is that the second column be less than 20100101.  This *condition* is, reasonably enough, written as `$2<20100101`.  Because we provide no *action*, awk does the default action which is to print the line.

Answer (score 4):

A Perl approach:

```
perl -ane 'print if $F[1]<20100101' file
```

The `-n` reads the input file line by line and applies the script given with `-e`. The `-a` makes `perl` behave like `awk`, it will automatically split each input line on whitespace and save each field as an element of array `@F`. So, the script itself will print a line if the second field (`F[1]`, arrays start at 0) is less than 20100101.

Answer (score 1):

shell version:

```
(while read l; do [ `echo  $l | cut -d ' ' -f 2` -lt 20100101 ] && echo $l; done) < file
```

Answer (score 0):

Java version (requires java compiler, personally I use openJDK)

Create a `*.java` file with the following contents:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;

public class secondColumn
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
{
    File inpFile = new File (args[0]);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(inpFile);
    String id = "";
    int num = 0;

    while (scan.hasNext())
        {

            id = scan.next();
            num = scan.nextInt();

    if ( num < 20100101  )
        System.out.println(id + " " + num);

        }

}

}
```

Compile and run like so:

```
xieerqi:$ javac secondColumn.java                                                                                          

xieerqi:$ java secondColumn inputFile.txt                                                                                  
id1 19501112
id2 19831207
1d3 20001212
id6 20000101
id10 20061213
id11 20081212
```

Answer (score 0):

For your Case 2 this can be done in Bash, for example save the file below as **split**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Usage:     ./split 'data.txt' 'value'

paired=(  )
value="$2"

while read -a paired
do
    [[ ${paired[1]} < $value ]] && 
        echo "${paired[@]}" >> lessthan.txt ||
        echo "${paired[@]}" >> morethan.txt
done < "$1"

# end file
```

Note that the variable **paired** is an array.  Using **read -a paired** reads each line into an array of pairs, zero-based, so element 1 is the number of interest in each row.  Argument 2 to **split** is the value to be used for splitting.

For your Case 1, I am not sure what you are wanting to do, but you can modify the above so that, as you read each line of the file, you can send column 1 `${paired[0]}` or column 2 `${paired[1]}` to any file you wish, depending upon the value of column 2.